# J-2 visa: who is funding for your trip?

Tags: usa, j-visa

We are applying for J visas, J-1 for me and J-2 for my wife. I don't know how to answer this question in my wife application form: "who is funding for your trip?".

In my application form, my employer is the one who is funding for my trip. But for my wife, is it me or my employer?

---

### UPDATE:

I would like to hear from people having experience filling these forms. My only aim is to fill them correctly.

@DCTLib explained my situation perfectly. J-2 is a dependent visa of J-1, and the sponsor is the same as J-1. This means on the paperwork, my employer is also the sponsor for my wife. That's why I don't know if I should put them as "funding for my wife's trip". Obviously no employer will pay for the wives of employees.

I'm applying VISA for a post doc position, if this matters.

Comment: I'm confused: surely you know whether your employer is paying for your wife or not?

Comment: @NateEldredge I think the question is about the "transitivity" of payment. Of course, the wife will get the money from the OP, and the OP will get it from the employer. The OP asks whether that makes - in the eyes of the consulate officer - the employer the source of the wife's income or not.

Comment: While your employer may not be paying for your wife, it is not obvious that no employer would pay for an employee's wife (or indeed husband) to accompany the employee in an overseas relocation.  Many do.

Comment: I filled in such forms 3 years ago, but don't recall answering such a question (which probably means I didn't worry about it). I would assume the safe answer would be to fill in the sponsor. Maybe this is relevant if there is some 3rd party that it is specifically funding the travel. A J-2 is in general not expected to work. There is a possibility of applying for a work permit, but I think the rule is that any extra income that would come from this is not needed for normal cost of living.

Comment: @JanJ: could you turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept and close this question :)

Comment: @qsp: sure, if you're satisfied with my recollection, I'll do so. Good luck with everything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filled in such forms 3 years ago, but don't recall answering such a question (which probably means I didn't worry about it). I would assume the safe answer would be to fill in the sponsor. Maybe this is relevant if there is some 3rd party that it is specifically funding the travel. A J-2 is in general not expected to work. There is a possibility of applying for a work permit (which is very often granted, but costs money and takes time), but at that time (I don't know if that has changed in the meantime) the rule is that any extra income that would come from this is not needed for normal cost of living.

Note: this information is based on my recollection of filling in these forms 3 years ago. This means that the information could be wrong or out of date.